# How do I force enable soft wrap in Intellij under the "long single string" exception?

Tags: intellij-idea

There is one exception where Intellij doesn't soft wrap. From the Intellij reference [page](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/general.html), under the "Soft Wraps" section, it states

`"However, in certain cases, when a line cannot be "soft-wrapped", the horizontal scroll bar still appears (for example, if a line consists of a single string that is wider than the visible area.)".`

How do I still force this case to wrap? It causes an annoying horizontal scroll bar and I want to disable it.

Comment: This issue was addressed in 2019.2: https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/nextversion/ .

Comment: Where is it addressed there? I don't see it...

Comment: It's fixed by [this commit](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/commit/9f9091a5bcd13fe7ffb2dfcdd4d5a82dfe695ebc).

Comment: So I just have to update to version 2019.2 and it will work?